# supervisor has logs breaks

Tags: python-3.6, supervisord

I add program which print text every 5 sec. to supervisor service and when I read a output logs there are somtimes breaks like below. Where is a problem?

I log to supervisorctrl and in this mode I : 
`tail test_s` 
and I have got sometimes breaks in report like below now I 15:06 and there is a pause

> ... You run test program using Supervisor at 15-02-52. Good job Darek
>   :). kupa4  ... You run test program using Supervisor at 15-02-57. Good
>   job Darek :). kupa4
>
> ... You run test program using Supervisor at 15-03-02. Good job Darek
>   :)

My program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys


while True:
    print(f"You run test program using Supervisor at {datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')}.")
    print("Good job Darek :).")
    print("...")
    time.sleep(5)
```

His configuration in supervisor

```
[program:test_s]
command=/home/darek/PycharmProjects/Small_programs/shell_scripts/test/test_s.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/test_s.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/test_s.out.log
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by breaks? Maybe you have an example output you can show us?

Comment: I log to supervisorctrl and in this mode I : tail test_s and I have got sometimes breaks in report like below now I 15:06 and there is a pause ...
You run test program using Supervisor at 15-02-52.
Good job Darek :).
kupa4
...
You run test program using Supervisor at 15-02-57.
Good job Darek :).
kupa4
...
You run test program using Supervisor at 15-03-02.
Good job Darek :).

Comment: Can you edit your main post with the output so it can be displayed more clearly, it's a bit difficult to follow in the comments.

Comment: I edit and past comment there.

Comment: Ok great, what is the "kupa4" part? You are not pritning out "kupa4" but it is appearing in your output? Also, it looks like it is outputting correctly as you are getting a new log message every 5 seconds.  I'm still not 100% clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your output is being buffered.  Have you tried disabling buffering?

You can do this by setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable in your `supervisord.conf` file like below:

```
[program:test_s]
environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
command=/home/darek/PycharmProjects/Small_programs/shell_scripts/test/test_s.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/test_s.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/test_s.out.log
```

Alternatively, you could run the script with the `-u` flag.

EDIT: If you wish to use the -u flag, you can modify your `supervisord.conf` like below:

```
command=python3 -u /home/darek/PycharmProjects/Small_programs/shell_scripts/test/test_s.py
```

Comment: Yes it solve me problem Thanks! :) But I have 2 more questions. Where I should use flag -u. And second now I edit program which should create new file .dat and write there something. Is it possible do this throw supervisor? When I run it from console it works, throught supervisor not :/

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you can use the -u flag.  This will  work in exactly the same way as PYTHONBUFFERED=1 environment variable, please can you mark my post as your answer :).  For your second question, yes you should be able to write to any file type just like you already are to a log file.  I suggest you post another question with more details so we can see what the exact problem is.

Comment: I on arrow up is it correct flag as answer to my post?

Comment: The arrow upvotes the answer but as the poster you can press the tick to correctly mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I see only "share edit flag" where in "flag" I have "spam" "rude or abusive " ...

Comment: Just below the score where you upvoted, you should see a grey tick box.  When you press on it, it will turn green and the answer will be marked.  Have a look here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow - if you see the answer is ticked with a green tick mark.  You should see it just below the score point.